# XeTeX in OpenBSD

Tags: xetex, installing, texlive, compiling, openbsd

How could I get XeTeX in OpenBSD?

I have tried to:

1. `pkg_add texlive_base-2012`, but it tries to install so much more that I ran out of space.
2. run the `install-tl` perl script for TL13, but even if I chose only the absolute bare minimum, it started to download all other stuff which I don't need. There wasn't binaries for OpenBSD so I thought NetBSD would be close enough. Alas, running `xetex` results in

   ```
   syntax error: `(' unexpected.
   ```
3. build from source, but this again failed partly because not enough space.
   I guess I could whip up a virtual machine and build it there, but I thought I'd ask here first.
4. use NetBSD's pkgsrc in OpenBSD, this failed in `x11-links` not finding X11 libs. Why would one need X11 for this is a little beyond me, but hey.
5. fetched binary distribution of TL on NetBSD-6.1.1; running `xetex` gave some  error about `libfontconfig.so.7.0` not found (though it did exist).
6. Installed a new virtual machine with enough space to hold the `texlive_base-2012`, `ldd`'ed the binary for libs and copied them over. Then I got `can't load library 'libfreetype.so.19.0'` (although I just copied it over). This is kinda bizarre, right?

Would you have a suggestion or precompiled binary for 5.3-i386?

Comment: I don't know if the NetBSD binaries will work on OpenBSD. Unfortunately the TL port hasn't been updated yet - 5.4 will still have TL2012. So building from source seems to be the way. Ask on [ports](http://www.openbsd.org/mail.html) first.

Comment: Did you try approach (2) but with TL2012? I think there was no-one available to do building for OpenBSD this year, hence it being dropped, but for last year I thought it was there in the 'vanilla' version. Of course, if you succeed in (3) then contributing a build would be great!

Comment: @Joseph: Nice idea. Though, I tried with the `install-tl` from [here](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2012/tlnet-final/), and gave it the `--repository=<above_mentioned_path>`, and I can't see OpenBSD binaries there.

Comment: @morbusg, what is the status of this question? Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Paul: No solution yet; once I have some time and free HD space, I'll try from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative route may be to use [compat_freebsd - setup for running  FreeBSD  binaries  under emulation](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/openbsd/man8/compat_freebsd.8.html) and use the FreeBSD [XeTeX port](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/print/tex-xetex/).